# array from C in Assembly

Tags: c, arrays, x86-64, sse, inline-assembly

I'm trying to do some adding with SSE and I'm using to this C with assembly. Why something like this doesn't work?

```
struct vector {
    float x1, x2, x3, x4;
};

struct vector *dodawanie(const struct vector v1[], const struct vector v2[], int size) {

struct vector vec[size];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        asm(
            "MOV %1, %%rax \n"
            "MOV %2, %%rdx \n"

            "MOVUPS (%%rax), %%xmm0 \n"
            "MOVUPS (%%rdx), %%xmm1 \n"
            "ADDPS %%xmm0, %%xmm1 \n"

            "MOVUPS %%xmm1, %0 \n"

            :"=g"(vec[i])       //wyjscie
            :"g"(v1[i]), "g"(v2[i]) //wejscie
            :"%rax", "%rdx"
        );
}
return vec;
}
```

I got error: Thread 1: *EXC_BAD_ACCESS (CODE = EXC_I386_GPFLT)*

But when instead of **v1[i], v2[i]** I put **v1, v2** etc. this work correctly but of course only with the first element of array.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: 1. take a look at generated asm it may happen that %1 and %2 are being passed by `rax`/`rdx`. 2. try to pass %1 and %2 directly by `rax` and `rdx`. Look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html#Machine-Constraints for x86 specific constraints

Comment: First I would be inclined to use compiler intrinsics for `addps`. If you are intent on using inline assembler I'd follow Michal's advice of looking at getting the assembler template to do most of the work. Assuming v1, v2, and vec are all arrays of vectors (__m128) then something like this may work  `asm(
            "MOVAPS %[v1], %[out]\n\t"
            "ADDPS %[v2], %[out]\n\t"
            :[out]"=&x,m"(vec[i])
            :[v1]"mx,x"(v1[i]), [v2]"mx,x"(v2[i])
        );`

Comment: Your code appears to be returning a pointer to a local variable which could cause some unexpected behavior since you are relying on the stack not being trashed after the function returns and before the data is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using values from tables ( `v1[i]`, `v2[i]` ) and you treat them as adresses (`"MOVUPS (%%rax), %%xmm0 \n"`). Use `&v1[i]` and `&v2[i]` respectively.

This is also why form `v1` and `v2` works as in such case address is being passed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's obviously and I didn't see this. Thanks to u I save a couple of minutes.